Debugging in R Studio
Have read a lot about debugging in R Studio, but still have a few basic questions:

Where do you place the debug() statements? Before the function definitions? Before library() statements?

Does setting Debug>On Error> Break on Code always cause the browser debug mode? Is there no way to debug the same way in the Editor? And if so how does one default to the editor?



This is more of a request for a tutorial instead of a specific programming question, which is what stack overflow is organized for. For those, google provides a few good resources like https://cosimameyer.com/post/mastering-debugging-in-r/ and https://github.com/jennybc/debugging#readme and https://rstats.wtf/debugging-r and https://shannonpileggi.github.io/debugging-nhsr/#/title-slide
